# Speeding up GeoJSON data in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, speed

I have a very large GeoJSON file and I would like to make it faster.

How can I add in the filter a check to see if points are inside the map's view box, so only points in the current view are rendered?

```js
 var str_pol = L.geoJson(null); 
// load GeoJSON from an external file
$.getJSON('https://url', function(data) {
  var strutt_poly = L.geoJson(data, {
      style: subteStyle,
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        var popupContent = "<p><b>Desc: </b>"+ feature.properties.desc+'</p>';
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
      layer.addTo(strutture_pol);
    }
  });
});
```

I tried to use the WFS service.

I have GeoServer to another server I can see the WMS layer but not WFS layer, why?

```js
    var sost_wms= L.tileLayer.wms("http://url:8080/geoserver/test/wms", {
        layers: 'test:sostegno',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true
    });

var case = L.geoJson(null);   
// load GeoJSON from an external file
$.getJSON('http://url:8080/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=test%3Acase&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson', function(data) {
  var casa= L.geoJson(data, {
      style: function(feature) {
      return {
       weight: 1,
                opacity: 1,
                color: '#000',
                dashArray: '3',
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                fillColor: '#ec7f1a'
      };
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        var popupContent = "<p><b>nome: </b>"+ feature.properties.nome+'</p>';

            layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
// aggiungi i dati del geojson al layer var clusters
      layer.addTo(case);
    }
  });
});
```

On my local server, I can see them both.

Comment: A filter won't help as GeoJSON has no spatial index so the program will still need to read the whole file to check each point. You should probably put your data in a database like postgis and use something like GeoServer to serve just the data you want.

Comment: they are already in a database but the file is still very large

Comment: WFS is your friend

Comment: Is it better then to create the geojson file from geoserver as a WFS service?

Comment: Probably CORS needs to be set up

Comment: postgres 11+ support st_geojson see http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/267-Creating-GeoJSON-Feature-Collections-with-JSON-and-PostGIS-functions.html for example